# Displaying Record Id instead Of Name for Lookup field in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have created a lwc component with  to display the output in . There is a custom lookup field in Account to Employee object. In the screen, instead of the employee name, employee id is displayed. Can someone please suggest what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see some code to better answer this question, but I believe you are using `Employee__c` instead of using `Employee__r.Name`?